# How can i limit one group per page in Cognos?

Tags: report, business-intelligence, cognos

I have a block with a list with 5 columns and i have grouped it on the first column. I have added sum aggregation below each group.

How can i limit results to show one group per page?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by using a *Page Set* as follows:

- Go to the *Report Pages* in the *Page Explorer*
- Drag a *Page Set* from the toolbox into *Report Pages*
- Drag your current report page into the *Detail Pages* folder of the new *Page Set*
- Click on the new *Page Set*
- In the properties of the *Page set*:

  - Select the query of your report page
  - Click on *Grouping and Sorting* (a small dialog box appears)
  - From the data items on the left drag the grouping criterion into the *Group* folder on the right.
  - Close dialog.
- Run the report.

The following figure shows the *Report Pages* windows after successful configuration.

[image: New Page Set Configuration]